# problem with html codes showing in textarea html code such as <p> and < br>

Tags: html, textarea

I'm doing something rather elementary - doing a `<textarea cols="60" rows="35">` textarea scrollable text box.... the problem im getting is html keeps popping up regardless of whether its written in wordpress html or text mode - in text mode on wordpress, when the selected say `<br>` is selected, it selects all the text, so i cant delete that or it will delete all the text....

Comment: What do you mean by "html keeps popping up"?

Comment: Are you trying to output unescaped HTML inside `<textarea>...</textarea>`?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear to me what your problem is exactly.  If you posted the problematic html we could use an editor to play around with it and try and help find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you aren't "closing" the textarea tag:

```
<textarea name="thingy" cols=10 rows=5></textarea>
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```